# controller does not exist laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, api, microservices

I'm trying to restructure some laravel files, I renamed app file to infrastructure and created an API file which will have all modules. I will create ... inside (app)infrastrucure. I modified RouterServiceProvider with this code, It will load the route inside module and if there isn't so it will load default route this work if I use inside my module

```
//inside api/purchase/route.php
Route::get('/purchase', function () {
echo 'go purchase';
});
```

but it doesn't work if i write like this

```
//inside api/purchase/route.php
$router->get('/purchase', 'PurchaseController@get');
```

I already create a controller with get method, but it said 
"Class Infrastructure\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController does not exist"

I already did composer install, composer dump, composer dump-autoload .. I added inside composer.json autoload the api and infrastructure directory.

```
//infrastructure/provider/routingserviceprovider.php
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
        {
            Route::group([
                'middleware' => 'web',
                'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            ], function ($router) {
                if($this->validateRoute())
                    require base_path('api/'.$this->moduleName.'/routes.php');

                require base_path('routes/web.php');
            });
        }

        private function validateRoute()
        {
            $path = $this->app->request->getRequestUri();
            $arrIndex = explode('/',$path);
            //Validate route
            $this->moduleName = empty($arrIndex[3]) ? null : $arrIndex[3];
            //Validate if the module exist
            return (!is_null($this->moduleName) && file_exists(base_path('api/'.$this->moduleName)));
        }
```

this is the error im getting
[image]

I wanna add N module inside api directory with their own routes.php files.

sry if I don't say property and thank you so much!

Comment: To my experience, this is usually a typo in either the filename, the class name in the file or the class name when you call it. Are you sure they all spells "PurchaseController" correctly? Remember PHP is case sensitive. Also it is likely that the namespace in the class file has typo. It should be `namespace Infrastructure\Http\Controllers` in your case.